# Visualize Bitcoin Hashing

Tags: hash, mining-technical-details, sha256

According to https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Hash,

> BitCoin uses the SHA-256 hash algorithm to generate verifiably
>   "random" numbers in a way that requires a predictable amount of CPU
>   effort. **Generating a SHA-256 hash with a value less than the current
>   target solves a block and wins you some coins.**

Here is an example for web logs; https://code.google.com/p/logstalgia/

Obviously solving the hash takes many iterations. I'm curious if there anything that currently lets you visualize a miner hashing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got linked this question.

I made a tool which includes a component that allows one to simulate mining:

http://yogh.io/#mine:last

It's not entirely accurate; it doesn't support BIP 34, so the block height is not reflected in the coinbase tx, and it's still got some bugs. Currently in alpha. But it can give you some pointers.

It'll construct a block on top of the tip of the current best chain, with a coinbase transaction and nothing else, then start hashing at 4 hashes/sec, showing every failed attempt (which at this hashrate, is likely to be all of them).

Comment: Wow, this is very pretty!

Comment: This is a great start! Do you have an open repo of your code?

Comment: Yep. Any help in testing or code contributions would be greatly appreciated, as would publicly hosting the project on top of a node. I was away for several weeks and haven't had a chance to work on the project further, I intend to pick up the pace in the coming weeks and get the project out of alpha/beta. Code here: https://github.com/JornC/bitcoin-transaction-explorer

Answer (score 0):

Check out: **[Mining Bitcoin with pencil and paper](http://www.righto.com/2014/09/mining-bitcoin-with-pencil-and-paper.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Mining Bitcoin with Excel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZBZPOEVyJA

:)

Comment: This answer would be much improved if you updated it to describe the video in a little more detail.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular Edit the answer yourself.